# How do I have to use Devexpress XPO in PRISM modular application?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, prism, xpo

I'm working on a project with 20+ Modules with the following Technics:

WPF 4.0 ,  PRISM 4 , Unity 2.0 , MVVM Light , and Devexpress XPO as and ORM

I have no idea how to plane to use a XPO Session in my modules?

I have faced the following items but don't know witch is the best?

1. Using a global static Session property
2. Use a global static connection string
3. Use a global static IDataLayer
4. use and Registered Interface in PRISM
5. or maybe you can give me a idea?

Comment: I would definitively remove the static global options. Register your session factory as a singleton (if they have something like that in XPO) in your ioc container and reference the interface through ctors throughout the system.

Comment: When I say "througout the system" I mean of course in the correct layer within your module (probably hidden behind your repositories or something like that)

Comment: Tanks Marius, after having a lot of trouble with using static in such a way I do agree with your suggestion.Using interface through ctors is the 4th item I have mentioned in the question. but I'm hesitated with the correct way you mentioned in the second comment.